# Get obj export settings (properties) from ExportOBJ class shown in the UI in python script

Tags: python, export

When I start blender, create an e.g. cube and want to export this cube as obj I do this via: 
 `File -> Export -> Wavefront (.obj)`
In the opened export dialog I see e.g. besides the last used file location the OBJ export properties like: `Selection Only, Animation etc.`
These properties are defined in `"<<blender location>>/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/__init__.py"` where the ExportOBJ class is registered as operator I think.

If I export my scene as OBJ via the `Wavefront (.obj)` UI dialog blender saves the last set property state values like `Selection Only`.

[image]

How can I get those property values in a python script?
So for the `Selection Only` a boolean like: 
`selection_only = bpy.ops.export_scene.obj.use_selection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Window manager methods**

Prior to running python console code below I have exported the  scene to wavefront obj, set a filepath and chosen use selection.

```
>>> wm = C.window_manager

>>> props = wm.operator_properties_last("export_scene.obj")
```

Running auto-complete `props.`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

```
>>> props.
          as_pointer(

          ... cut for brevity...


          use_normals
          use_nurbs
          use_selection
          use_smooth_groups
          use_smooth_groups_bitflags
          use_triangles
          use_uvs
          use_vertex_groups
          values(
>>> props.
```

Can get any property value

```
>>> props.use_uvs
True
```

This is the default value for `use_uvs`

If however we iterate over items, will get those values last used that are non default.

```
>>> for k, v in props.items():
...     k, v
...     
('filepath', '/home/batfinger/Desktop/untitled.obj')
('use_selection', 1)
```

To run the operator again using the same properties from code could simply make this a dictionary and pass it to the operator as *kwargs*

```
>>> d = {k : v for k, v in props.items()} # or d = dict(props.items())
>>> bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(**d)
Progress:   0.00%
    (  0.0003 sec |   0.0000 sec) OBJ Export path: '/home/batfinger/Desktop/untitled.obj'
Progress:   0.00%
Progress:   8.33%
Progress:  16.67%
Progress:  25.00%
Progress:  33.33%
Progress:  41.67%
Progress:  50.00%
          (  0.0044 sec |   0.0034 sec) Finished writing geometry of 'Cube'.
Progress:  50.00%
Progress:  50.00%
Progress:  50.00%
      (  0.0058 sec |   0.0051 sec) Finished exporting geometry, now exporting materials
Progress: 100.00%
NO NODES!
      (  0.0074 sec |   0.0067 sec) OBJ Export Finished
Progress: 100.00%
Progress: 100.00%
Progress: 100.00%
Progress: 100.00%

{'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Thank you that's the solution :) I searched the whole web for a solution and browsed through the api docs. How did you know about it?